# How to enable blinkers (indicator lights) in Autoware.ai when turning?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Might be abit too general question, but maybe someone can give a good starting point.

How to best implement the functionality of flashing blinkers (indicator lights) when turning using Autoware.ai and possibly openplanner?

- There is LaneType attribute in map (lane.csv) where 0 - forward, 1 - turn left, 2 - turn right

Also have found following topics:

- /indicator_cmd (autoware_msgs/IndicatorCmd)
- /lamp_cmd (autoware_msgs/IndicatorCmd)
- /turn_signal_cmd (dbw_mkz_msgs/TurnSignal)

Open to all suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351504/how-to-enable-blinkers-(indicator-lights)-in-autoware.ai-when-turning?/) by [edgar](https://answers.ros.org/users/54451/edgar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2020-05-07**:
the values in lane.csv is used for global planning. and it is not semantically the same as activating blinkers.
open planner currently doesn't send this information.

**Comment by [edgar](https://answers.ros.org/users/54451/edgar/) on 2020-05-07**:
Thank you! So, there is nothing in openplanner currently that is sending the information for turning on egocar's blinkers when it is turning?

There is for example: `PlanningHelpers::GetIndicatorsFromPath` - so this and all the other inidicator related stuff in code is to determine and predict the actions of other vehicles?

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2020-05-08**:
Exactly, it is only for intention estimation.
the logic for the ego vehicle decision making should be more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like `twist_gate` listens to `/lamp_cmd`, which is usually produced by Decision Maker. `twist_gate` should then pass this along as part of the VehicleCmd message type to your vehicle interface (looks like you're using a DataSpeed DBW system). You may need to have some node parse out the `lamp_cmd` from the VehicleCmd and send a message to `/turn_signal_cmd` to activate it in your DBW system as this is not part of Autoware.ai currently.

In fact, if you would like to contribute a DataSpeed interface package to Autoware.ai, contributions are always welcome! (keeping in mind that feature additions will end at the end of 2020 [as described here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/end-of-life-dates-for-autoware-ai/13750))

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edgar](https://answers.ros.org/users/54451/edgar/) on 2020-05-07**:
Thank You for your answer!

No, not DataSpeed DBW. Actually AStuff PACMod :). I've copied a bit wrong thing into my original post.
So there is `/turn_signal_command` (automotive_platform_msgs/TurnSignalCommand) in PacMOD

So do I understand correctly? SSC_interface listens to `/vehicle_cmd` and it includes also information of blinkers: `/lamp_cmd`. It publishes `/ssc/turn_signal_command` that should trigger the corresponding vehicle controllers and thus blinkers, if said so in /lamp_cmd message.

So I need to get the information to /lamp_cmd, but currently it seems that in OpenPlanner there is nothing that publishes anything about egocar blinkers.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-05-07**:
Yes, this appears to be correct. Since you are using AutonomouStuff's SSC, I would recommend getting in touch with their support team. Their Open Autonomy Team may be able to provide a quick fix for this issue.

Please remember to accept this answer (the checkbox under the up/down buttons) if it was helpful.